# No identifica "FOR" dentro de otro "FOR"

Tags: java, android, bucle-for

No me identifica el segundo dcara o solo lo ignorase totalmente.

**MODIFICACION ACTUpuesta si el objeto del registro de la lista es igual al de la otra lista que no me agregue nada y que siga, pero si no son iguales que los agregue.

**Mi problema en sí es:**

Me agrega en el `else` dentro del `else`(donde se encuentran ambos `for`), pese a que el usuario ya existe y acá unas capturas de eso, haciendo que mi aplicación ocupe espacio de más.

Por ejemplo, tenuchas gracias.

**USUARIOS IF ES LA IMPRESION DE LA LISTA `empleadossqlite` al final de esto**
[![Resultado de haber ejecutado por 2da,tercera vez el programa][1]][1]

```java
if(empleadossqlite.size() == 0 || empleadossqlite==null){
                            Log.i("IGUAL A 0","LISTA SIN DATOS:");
                            for(Empleado api : empleados){

                                localadapter = (EmpleadoAdapter) empleadosList.getAdapter();
                                localadapter.setEmpleados(empleadossqlite);
                                localadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                        }else{
                            for(Empleado local : empleados){
                                Log.i("CON DATOS","LISTA CON DATOS:");
                                for(Empleado comp : empleadossqlite){
                                    if (comp.getcod_USUARIO().equals(local.getcod_USUARIO())){
                                        Log.e("EXISTE","EXISTE EL EMPLEADO");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        EmpleadoRepository.create()
                                        localadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: Bievenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor mejora la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Evita poner capturas de imagen con código, cámbialo por el texto, es más fácil para ti (copiar y pegar) y para nosotros, ya que las imágenes se ven con dificultad en dispositivos pequeños y si se quiere obtener parte del código para hacer pruebas es imposible.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, por favor edita tu pregunta en base a [ask], revisa otras preguntas por favor.

Comment: cambia las fotos del código por, tu código en formato de texto por favor

Comment: Hola, ya modifique y le puse el codigo, espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias.

Comment: Asegúrate de que la colección no sea nula (`empleadossqlite`), sobretodo si estás haciendo alguna consulta asíncrona antes de la llamada de ambos loops. Hace falta más código para verificar si realmente no entra, porque tienes el Log dentro de una condición y puede ser que dicha condición nunca se cumpla. Pon el log fuera de las condiciones y verifica que la lista no sea `null`.

Comment: Sí señor@Andrespengineer, voy a asegurarme creo que lo que me comunica me acaba de dar una idea, gracias.

Comment: Aun no funciona T.T, alguine help

Comment: Cuál es la finalidad de los for anidados que tienes?

Comment: Quieres acceder a una lista de objetos y después acceder a una lista que un objeto tiene o como?

Comment: @SideralBebarmy no te desesperes, mientras mejor realices tus preguntas, obtendras una respuesta mejor, saludos!

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo, sr @Jorgesys

Answer (score 2):

**La razòn por la cual no entra al `for` es simplemente porque este listado no contiene elementos.**

Si deseas sabes porque no entra al `for`, puedes determinar si el `List` contiene elementos, mediante el mètodo `size()`, si la medida del listado es mayor a 0, entrara al `for`.

```
  System.out.println("Cuantos elementos tiene empleados? " + empleados.size()"));
```

Por lo tanto puedes imprimir y determinar porque no entra de esta forma:

```
System.out.println("Entra al primer for? " + (empleados.size()>0? "si!":"no!"));      
for (Empleado local : empleados) {
System.out.println("Entra al segundo for? " + (empleadossqlite.size()>0? "si!":"no!"));      
  for (Empleado comp : empleadossqlite) {

    if (comp.getcod_USUARIO().equals(local.getcod_USUARIO())) {
        Log.i("EXISTE", "Este usuario ya existe");
    } else {
      EmpleadoRepository.create(local.getcod_USUARIO(), local.getCOD_TIP_USUARIO(), local.getCOD_AREA(),
      local.getFLG_PROYECTO(), local.getCOD_PROYECTO(), local.getFLG_FILTRARBUSQUEDA(), local.getApellido(),
      local.getNombre(), local.getCelular1(), local.getCelular2(), local.getCorreopersonal(), local.getCorreoempresa(),
      local.getFnacimiento(), local.getUnidad(), local.getSector(), local.getOcupacion(), local.getDni());
      localadapter = (EmpleadoAdapter) empleadosList.getAdapter();
      localadapter.setEmpleados(empleadossqlite);
      localadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      //return;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Linda respuesta y ayuda, pues mi objetivo para ser más claros es llenar la lista de empleadossqlite (QUE INICIALMENTE ESTÁ VACIA AL MOMENTO DE SER INSTALADA EN EL MOVIL POR PRIMERA VEZ) y que esta se llene por datos del empleado, por eso hice el if de comparación pero ahora que lo pienso si no hay datos en el sqlite entonces como puede hacer la comparación, pero acaso igualmente no tendría que dejarle llenar los datos?, su respuesta me ha servido mucho como reflexion, si ud me entiende podría ayudarme a buscar una solución aunque tambien acabo de pensar en una ahora mismo, demasiadas gracias.